# Need assist - Converting Windows Media Server to Ubuntu

Tags: raid, headless, mediaserver

I found this guide but have a few questions:
http://dagolav.prestegarden.com/installing-ubuntu-on-the-hp-mediasmart-ex490/

I'm not a Linux guru yet, fairly new. I want to convert this sweet little network storage server device (HP Windows Media Server) into an Ubuntu storage server.

My questions are as follows:
1) The guide mentions the SiS191 network card on this board is not supported by the Ubuntu 10.04 SiS191 drivers. Is this still the case with more recent Ubuntu builds? Since an older chipset, I'm guessing probably still not supported. Not sure how to research this to get an answer myself (still too new to Linux).

2) The chassi of this box supports 5 hard disk drive bays. I'm going to attempt this as headless install (as guide suggests using another PC machine to boot, format and install ubuntu, then move drives into device and try remoting in).  To add additional hard drives into the chassis, will Ubuntu server auto-detect these on bootup after I add the hard disks physically into the bays? I wasn't planning to set any advanced raid up. I'll research the onboard raid controller, the Windows Media Server software did auto-recognize all hard drives and by default just showed a virtualized storage space - but I don't believe it was doing any raid fault tolerance on the drive and the storage was just a virtual pool managed by the software. It was long ago I set it up and I think at one point there was a config option in the software, but I didn't do any mirroring or striping.

I'm sure as I go though this I'm likely to have more questions - part of this exercise is to go through a full server build to get more experience with Linux management. Thanks in advance, apologies if these are overly 'noob' questions -

c

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is probably I found the man page for the sis drivers for Ubuntu 12.04 precise at [Ubuntu Manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/sge.4freebsd.html).

I also know that there a a couple different options for setting up a RAID configuration and one of the newer

[SnapRaid](http://snapraid.sourceforge.net/compare.html)